# NIO selector.select() not working properly on long poll HTTP since Android 2.3?

Tags: android, networking, nio

I use comet style communication with my android app. It worked all fine until I used Gingerbread (Emulator, CyanogenMod 7). The problem I have is that

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();
channel.configureBlocking(false);
channel.connect(socketAddress);
channel.socket().setKeepAlive(true);
channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ);

if(selector.select() > 0){
 //DO STUFF
}
```

the

```
selector.select()>0
```

returned true if I sent an event from the server but now it just ignores it. Exactly the same code works in Android 1.6 - 2.2

I think this is a bug... someone can confirm the same issue or provide a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution, but not why it worked before.

```
channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

does not work anymore.

I had to register another selector only dealing with OP_READ and now it works.

```
channel.register(readSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
channel.register(connectSelector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);

if(connectSelector.select() > 0){
   //Do connect stuff
} else if(readSelector.select() > 0){
   //Do read stuff
}
```

I hope this saves some headaches.

EDIT:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15055

I posted it as a issue on the android issuetracker and it is under investigation

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue.  When I try to send something the selector does not get out of the blocking mode.  So I can only recieve the network packets and not send any.  I will give this a shot and let you know.  I am running android 2.3.3 on a nexus one.

Comment: Yes splitting up into two different selectors works for me.  A bit of pain but oh well - at least it works now.